# Terraform - assign multiple subnets to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 subnets (1 per availability zone)

```
resource "aws_subnet" "infrastructure_services" {
  count                   = "${var.enable_infrastructure_services_subnet ? 2 : 0}"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.this.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${cidrsubnet(var.cidr_block,5,count.index + 6)}"
  availability_zone       = "${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = "${
    merge( map("Name", format("%s %s %s", var.env_name, count.index == 0 ? "Infrastructure Services A" : "Infrastructure Services B", "Subnet")), 
    var.global_tags, 
    var.vpc_tags)}"
}
```

I want to add these 2 subnets to EC2 instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  count                   = "${length(var.instance_names)}"
  ami                     = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type           = "${element(var.instance_type, count.index)}"
  availability_zone       = "${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}"
  disable_api_termination = "${var.disable_api_termination}"
  key_name                = "${var.key_name}"
  ebs_optimized           = "${var.ebs_optimized}"
  subnet_id="${element(aws_subnet.infrastructure_services.id,count.index)}"

  vpc_security_group_ids=["${aws_security_group.infrastructure_services.id}"]
```

but getting:

```
aws_instance.this[0]: Resource 'aws_subnet.infrastructure_services' not found for variable 'aws_subnet.infrastructure_services.id'
* aws_instance.this[1]: Resource 'aws_subnet.infrastructure_services' not found for variable 'aws_subnet.infrastructure_services.id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `*` splat operator syntax from your list. Instead you should use `aws_subnet.infrastructure_services.*.id` to refer to a list of resources.

So instead your instance resource should look like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  count                   = "${length(var.instance_names)}"
  ami                     = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type           = "${element(var.instance_type, count.index)}"
  availability_zone       = "${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}"
  disable_api_termination = "${var.disable_api_termination}"
  key_name                = "${var.key_name}"
  ebs_optimized           = "${var.ebs_optimized}"
  subnet_id               = "${element(aws_subnet.infrastructure_services.*id, count.index)}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${aws_security_group.infrastructure_services.id}"]
}
```

It's probably also worth noting that unless you need to loop back through the list with the modulo of the length of the list then you can use the simpler `list[index]` syntax rather than `element(list, index])`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  count                   = "${length(var.instance_names)}"
  ami                     = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type           = "${var.instance_type[count.index]}"
  availability_zone       = "${var.availability_zones[count.index])}"
  disable_api_termination = "${var.disable_api_termination}"
  key_name                = "${var.key_name}"
  ebs_optimized           = "${var.ebs_optimized}"
  subnet_id               = "${aws_subnet.infrastructure_services.*id[count.index])}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${aws_security_group.infrastructure_services.id}"]
}
```